# TransportRequestHandler Exception in Spark with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am facing below issue while submitting spark job in client mode on datastax Cassandra cluster.

```
ERROR 2018-01-12 08:39:34,927 
org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler: Error sending result 
StreamResponse{streamId=/jars/OLVOracleDataExtraction-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar, 
byteCount=108938681, body=FileSegmentManagedBuffer{file=/home/cassandra/deploy/olv_extraction/OLVOracleDataExtraction-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar, 
offset=0, length=108938681}} to /10.73.115.11:35656; closing connection
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
```

Can some onehelp on this?

Comment: @ Chandra  were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same error